# Android Studio 4.0 Title Bar Missing

Tags: android-studio, title-bar

Since I upgraded to Android Studio 4.0, the standard Windows title bar has disappeared.

This makes it really difficult to move Android Studio windows around the screen because there is no title bar to click on to drag the window around. I have to try and find an empty pixel area to click on so I can drag it around. This is time consuming and really annoying.

The only way I can get around this is to horizontally stretch the window to create a blank space between the project name and the minimise icon.
[image]

I have Googled and cannot find any option to put the title bar back to the way it was in previous versions. Other than reinstalling an older Android Studio version, is there another way to turn the "classic" Windows title bar back on?

Comment: pretty sure the projectname can be used to drag the window around.

Comment: @LPChip yeah it can. Still means you can only use that small area to move it around though. It's also harder to see where one instance of Android Studio is when sitting on top of another instance because they're both the same colour with no contrast between the two.

Comment: The area the project name is stated is the title bar area. So technically it did not disappear. Its just that modern apps seem to push towards putting the menu in there to make things more compact, but with a large menu that only works if you have a big window, which you only can with a large monitor. There are apps that allow you to drag windows everywhere as long as it doesn't have a clickable function below it. You may want to search for that

Comment: @LPChip Alt-Space and M works as well :-)

Comment: If I could change the colour of the title bar that would help. I open another Android Studio instance and sit there waiting for it to start, not realising it is already open and sitting on top of an existing project. I just can't tell because it all blends in.